# Term for someone who calls herself negative things that are not true

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the correct term for someone who usually says negative things about herself (that she is fat,ugly or dumb) even though she knows that she is not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The act is called [self-deprecation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-deprecation), and so one could conclude that a person who does this is a **self-deprecator** (the term does not appear in most dictionaries but is easily understood and has been used before).

Comment: Self depreciation can also include acting humble 'Oh shush you, I'm not a _that_ good baker'.

Answer (score 0):

An **attention-seeker** or a **drama queen** will use self-depreciation to to draw attention to themself to seek affirmation. But people can be attention seekers or drama queens in other ways too, for example 'Look at me!' behavour, or causing drama externally.